# How to run an existing CakePHP project in xamp(localhost)

Tags: cakephp-3.0

i have been assigned to a new project with Cake PHP to do some modifications on it, the project already exists and i'm having trouble run it, i don't know how to run the project on my xamp local server, should i download cakePHP in the project( if so, how to do it ?) or there are some commands i should run to get the dependencies of CakePHP and run the application ( if so, what are these commands). thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- be sure that your php version >= 5.6.0
- you should firstly install composer https://getcomposer.org/download/
- then create new project by composer read the manual https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html

Or
- download the full project of Cakephp 3.0 https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/archive/master.zip
- unzip the archive in /xampp/htdocs/

Answer (score 0):

- if you haven't, install composer https://getcomposer.org/download/
- git bash into the directory then you can `composer update`
- and all    you need to do is go to localhost/